# boost::multi_index using custom key extractor syntax question?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I am applying example 6 of boost multi_index examples. 
  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example6

I am still learning the syntax of key extraction.i find that `member` key extractor require for its third argument a pointer to `class` member of type `type` where class is first arg and type is second arg .

```
template<class Class,typename Type,Type Class::*PtrToMember>
struct member;
```

But in example 6 the author uses 3rd arg which is not pointer .....

```
key_from_key< 
  member<car_manufacturer,
         const std::string, 
         &car_manufacturer::name>, 
  member<car_model, 
         const car_manufacturer *, 
         car_model::manufacturer> >
```

this should be `&` to make pointer which points to the member of class `car_model` of type `const car_manufacturer *` so giving us `pointer to pointer` .....but he just use the member identifier`car_model::manufacturer` which is only pointer to member.
So why did the author omits the `&` from third argument??

if any more code required i will put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, you found an error in Boost.MultiIndex docs :-)

It should be `&car_model::manufacturer` rather than `car_model::manufacturer`, as you correctly point out. What's more, `car_model::manufacturer` is not even legal C++, as, if anything, it would declare a *reference* to a member, which [does not exist in the language](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.mptr#4).

Additionally, the docs say:

```
struct car_model
{
  std::string       model;
  car_manufacturer* manufacturer;
  int               price;
};
```

where it should be (as correctly written in the actual code):

```
struct car_model
{
  std::string             model;
  const car_manufacturer* manufacturer;
  int                     price;
};
```

Otherwise, `member<car_model,const car_manufacturer *,&car_model::manufacturer>` wouldn't match the type of the `manufacturer` member.

I'll fix all of this in the docs. Thanks for spotting the mess.

Comment: i do not understand `car::manufacturer is not even legal C++`  ?what is `car::manufacturer` do you mean `car_manufacturer`?and what difference do `const` do? i am still new to c++ .in the first struct ,`manufacturer` is pointer to `struct car_manufacturer` which is `non const`"to me this means it could be changed" and in code it is `pointer to const same struct` `car_manufacturer` So why the first is declaring `reference` "not pointer" and the second declaring `pointer`?.i read the link you gave and its `third point` is talking about `member of reference type`?where is the reference `&` sign??

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, I meant `car_model::manufacturer` rather han `car::manufacturer`. The rest of your message about `const`ness and pointers I'm afraid to say I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,why does adding `const` make code works?in the first struct `car_model::manufacturer` is pointer to non const struct `car_manufacturer` type .But u said this is wrong and the right code  is to add `const`.what do adding `const` do to make code legal c++? in the sentence`"it would declare a reference to a member" `do you mean by `reference` lvalue or rvalue reference which use `&` sign Or do you mean by `reference` a `pointer`???excuse my ignorance..thanks again.by the way your library is amazing once i could learn it

Comment: What I mean is, if you have `struct X{some_type x;};` then `member`has to match the type of `x`, i.e, be of the form `member<X,some_type,&X::x>`. In the code, `manufacturer` is a `const car_manufacturer*`, matching with  `member<car_model,const car_manufacturer *,&car_model::manufacturer>`. Dropping `const` on either place would result in a mismatch.